# How to set cell value dependent on another cell with variable position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a strange task to perform and I can't imagine how to do it or even come up with a term to google, since I'm not that good with excel formulas, and I am not allowed to use VBA:

If column 'D' contains either an 'S' or an 'H' the following needs to be done:

1. Go to column 'E' in the same row
2. Find the first cell in column 'E' that holds a value by *moving upwards*
3. Go to the right to column 'F'
4. Copy that value to the cell in column 'B', in the row where you started

I know it's confusing, so I'm adding a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

There are some conditions:

- As I mentioned, I am not allowed to use VBA.
- The amount of rows can change, I guess more will be added.
- It apparently needs to be only a formula so it can be copy and pasted when new rows are added.

I hope I made myself clear, since english is not my native language. Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(OR(D2="S",D2="H"),INDEX(F:F,MATCH(LOOKUP(2,1/(ISNUMBER(E$1:INDEX(E:E,ROW(E1)))),E$1:INDEX(E:E,ROW(E1))),E:E,0)),"")
```

Drag down...

Comment: Thanks! I need to convert this to the german words for excel formulas and try it out, then I can give feedback

Comment: As always, great solution :) you can also combine it with `VLOOKUP`: `=IF(OR(D2="S",D2="H"),INDEX(F:F,MATCH(VLOOKUP(10^308,E$1:INDEX(E:E,ROW(E1)),1,1),E:E,0)),"")`

Comment: That might even be cleaner @JustynaMK

Comment: Holy guacamoly, it actually works! Had to replace the words for the functions and the comma with semikolons to make it work in german excel, but it's really the solution I need! Many Thanks!